# Fixed image like effect

Tags: jquery, html

Hello I have a general web question. I've been seeing a specific effect lately and am hoping someone can tell me the name of this effect and how it is done. The effect can be seen here: http://www.somoslr.com/. On a desktop, this site has an effect that acts like multiple fixed background images, but on a mobile device it acts as a standard site. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that they just used `$('body').css('background-image', url(blah.png)');` once a div (I'm assuming it's the one at the bottom) reaches a certain distance (`document.getElementById("div").scrollTop;`). Of course, they must've found the height of the window using `window.innerHeight` and went from there.

Answer (score 0):

The effect is called '[Parallax](http://www.awwwards.com/30-great-websites-with-parallax-scrolling.html)' and the website in question is using the [Stellar.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) library by Mark Dalgleish.

His library has some built in extra functionality to make everything work properly on Mobile devices...